# Using UPDATE with CASE conditions in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to change the value of a field on **table_1** based on some comparisons beetween values in **table_1** and **table_2**. So I'm using a **CASE** statement inside a **UPDATE** statement.
But with the code below, I'm getting an error message: 'Syntax error'.

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET value_1 =  CASE
                 WHEN table_1.x = table_2.y THEN 'OK'
                 WHEN table_1.x <> table_2.y THEN 'NOT OK'
               END
               FROM table_2
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support `from` in the `update`.  You need to use a correlated subquery:

```
update table_1 
    set value_1 = (case when exists (select 1 from table_2 where table_1.x = table_2.y)
                        then 'OK' else 'NOT OK'
                   end);
```

Comment: You just solved my problem, thks. But let me ask you, there's some special reason for why did you use the number one in: ... select **1** from table_2?

Comment: @SérgioLuisClem . . . `exists` simply checks whether the subquery returns any rows.  `select` requires some expression, and `1` is the easiest thing to type.